# Java как ввести данные сразу как маcсив String

Tags: java, scanner, binary, дерево

Проблема в том что на одном сайте при проверке решения задания, входные данные подаются как String[] вот так -

```
new String[] {"(1,2)", "(2,4)", "(5,7)", "(7,2)", "(9,5)"}
```

Я знаю как только по одному элементу принимать данные, например введенные с клавиатуры. В интернете пока не могу найти ничего, полазил поискал через точку и в BufferReader и в сканере, тоже не получилось. Изначально данные беру вот так -

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String incomingData = s.nextLine();
```

Вторая строчка кода (вот ета String incomingData = s.nextLine();) и есть 242 строкой где ошибка происходит, ошибка понятна, но как организовать отбор данных под условия сайта не знаю.
А сайт выдает такое:

```
Main.java:242: error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String
String incomingData = new String[] {"(1,2)", "(3,2)", "(2,12)", "(5,2)"};
```

Самое решение задания работает в Intellij IDEA, но работает на отбор одного элемента массива за раз, а при проверке через сайт - их отбор данных убивает - не сталкивался с таким раньше, помогите. Подскажите как выйти с положения
Осноной код здесть, строка 242 та же самая на гитХабе: https://github.com/zaharovmykola/try-with-tasks/blob/master/src/ThirdTask.java

Само задание вот:
Tree Constructor
Have the function TreeConstructor(strArr) take the array of strings stored in strArr, which will contain pairs of integers in the following format: (i1,i2), where i1 represents a child node in a tree and the second integer i2 signifies that it is the parent of i1. For example: if strArr is ["(1,2)", "(2,4)", "(7,2)"], then this forms the following tree: which you can see forms a proper binary tree. Your program should, in this case, return the string true because a valid binary tree can be formed. If a proper binary tree cannot be formed with the integer pairs, then return the string false. All of the integers within the tree will be unique, which means there can only be one node in the tree with the given integer value.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111403/discussion-on-question-by--java------c-string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось зайти на сайт чтоб выяснить ваш проблему.

Вам нужно начинать с того что дано массив строк на входе .

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Main {

  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] input = s.nextLine();
    for(String items: input) {
      System.out.println(items); // тут уже сидит ввод "(1,2)"
    }
  }

}
```

PS. Не создавайте новых классов так как они требуют отдельного файла. Эта площадка предполагает знания, и тестирует их. Не пользуйтесь вашим IDE, поскольку площадка предполагает написание решения на месте, как бы при онлайн тестировании.

UPD.

Вот вам решение задачи для данного сайта.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Main {

  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] input = s.nextLine();
    Map<Integer, Integer> tree = new TreeMap<>();
    for(String items: input) {
      Integer firstVertex = new Integer(items.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(",")[0]);
      Integer secondVertex = new Integer(items.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(",")[1]);
      
      
      if (tree.containsKey(firstVertex)) {
            tree.replace(firstVertex, tree.get(firstVertex) + 1);            
          } else {
            tree.put(firstVertex, 1);            
          }
      

      if (tree.containsKey(secondVertex)) {
            tree.replace(secondVertex, tree.get(secondVertex) + 1);            
          } else {
            tree.put(secondVertex, 1);            
          }
    }
    
    Boolean result = true;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> pair : tree.entrySet()) {
      if (pair.getValue() > 3) {
        result = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
  }

}
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Если ответ вам помог то можете пометить его как полезный